# InVBA, need a program to search through a row for a specific value(X), then in specific columns that share same row as X need to print those values(Y)

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA. I am trying to create a macro that will search worksheet1 for a specific value in Column A (i.e "EM - Easy Money", "P - Profit"). The row position of these specific values can change as new reports are uploaded. Once this value is found, I need to look at the values that share the same row as "EM - Easy Money" in specific column titles (i.e "Canada", "USA", "Mexico")
*the dataset contains additional column titles but not every column title is needed, just these select titles. However, when working with a new dataset the position of the titles can be in different column positions*

After this, I need to print the results of the value from Canada, USA, Mexico in a different worksheet (worksheet2) at cell positions that will always be the same.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub dataReport()

'for loop for vertical range (EM & P)

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SrchRng1 As Range, cel1 As Range
Dim emRow As Long, pRow As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("worksheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("workseet2")

Set SrchRng1 = ws1.Range("A15:A100")

For Each cel1 In SrchRng1

    If InStr(1, cel1.Value, "EM - Easy Money") > 0 Then
        emRow = ws1.Range("cel1").Row

    ElseIf InStr(1, cel1.Value, "P - Profit") > 0 Then
        pRow = ws1.Range("cel1").Row

    End If
Next cel1

'for loop for horizontal range followed by if statements for different world segments
Dim SrchRng2 As Range, cel2 As Range

Set SrchRng2 = ws1.Range("B13:BA14")

Dim canadaCol As Long, canadaEM As Range, canadaP As Range

For Each cel2 In SrchRng2

    'Canada

    If InStr(1, cel2.Value, "C_Canada") > 0 Then
        canadaCol = ws1.Range("cel2").Column

        canadaEM = Range(Cells(emRow, canadaCol))
        canadaP = Range(Cells(pRow, canadaCol))

        ws1.Range(canadaEM).Copy
        ws2.Range("F8").PasteSpecial

        ws1.Range(canadaP).Copy
        ws2.Range("F27").PasteSpecial
 
    End If
Next cel2

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems like a INDEX/MATCH/MATCH will do what you want.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of how to do this? @ScottCraner

Comment: `=INDEX(worksheet1!$A:$ZZ,MATCH("EM - Easy Money",worksheet1!$A$15:$A$100,0),MATCH("C_Canada",worksheet1!$A$13:$ZZ$13,0))`

Comment: Sorry, I am having one small issue that I cant seem to understand. MATCH("C_Canada",worksheet1!$A$13:$ZZ$13,0)) - This portion will not solve in excel for some reason, even though the value is included in the array. Any suggestions? @ScottCraner

Comment: Then one of C_Canada is different.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm dear ace,
I rather can recognize which var you count upwards, or downwards

For Each cel1 In SrchRng1

```
If InStr(1, cel1.Value, "EM - Easy Money") > 0 Then
    emRow = ws1.Range("cel1").Row

ElseIf InStr(1, cel1.Value, "P - Profit") > 0 Then
    pRow = ws1.Range("cel1").Row

End If
```

Next cel1

As it is will not work and Excel has a Maximum for the rows as for the columnrs and you should insert what your VBA should do if your loop runs out of these limits.

Answer (score 0):

You should SET your tables completly with THISWORKBOOK

```
PRIVATE CONST MaxRow=1048576
PRIVATE CONST MaxCol=16384

Dim ws1Obj AS Worksheet
Dim ws2Obj AS Worksheet

Dim RowObj AS Row
Dim ColObj AS Col
Dim r, c AS Int
Dim RowObj AS Range
Dim ColumnObj AS Range
Dim CellObj AS Range
Dim EM AS STRING

SET ws1Obj = Thisworkbook.sheets("ws1")
EM="em"
c=1 'This initialation is necesary because of the use of the FOR EACH-Loop
r=1 'Your rownumber
SET RowObj = ws1Obj.Range(r,c)

FOR EACH c IN RowObj
IF c > MaxCol Then EXIT FOR
IF ws1Obj.Cells(r,c) = EM Then EXIT FOR 'fullfills your Instr-condition
NEXT

r=1 'This initialation is necesary because of the use of the FOR EACH-Loop 
IF (c < MaxCol) Then 'found your Instr
SET ColObj = ws1Obj.cells(r, c)
FOR EACH r IN ColObj
IF r > MaxRow
IF ws1Obj.Cells(r, c) = EM Then EXIT FOR 'Your Instr-condition
NEXT
END IF

IF r < MaxRows
SET ws2Obj = Thisworkbook.sheets("ws2") 'Replace ws2 with the part of cells string
PRINT ws2Obj
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend to print out your "ws2" like this

```
PrintOut ws2Obj Copies=1 'This line prints the entire table

'If you want a certain Range in ws2 SET this Range in another Obj
Dim ws2PrintObj 'Insert this line at the top of the code 
                'where the other variable   are defined

SET ws2PrintObj=ws2Obj.Range(A1,Q51)
PrintOut ws2PrintObj
```

Dont`t hesitade to ask more I`d be very happy to help you more.